# Adding multiple array lists in groovy

Tags: groovy

I define a variable such as this:

`project.ext.SRC=["component_1.c","component_2.c"]`

I want to append two more array lists to this. Say as follows,

```
SRC += project(':someOtherGradleProject').ext.SRC + project(':yetAnotherGradleProject').ext.SRC
```

Is there a more elegant way of adding more arrayLists in Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

One sidenote, you don't need `.ext`.
This is only necessary on the first write of a property that does not exist yet, but not for subsequent writes or reads.

How about

```
SRC = allprojects.SRC.sum()
```